# propositional logic involve implication simplify

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$(\neg p \vee q)\rightarrow(r \vee \neg q)$$

How can I simplify this equation? I am really confused with the rules and I really need this as a example.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

**Implication**

$P \rightarrow Q \Leftrightarrow \neg P \lor Q$

Applied to your statement:

$$(\neg p \lor q)\rightarrow(r \lor \neg q) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$\neg (\neg p \lor q)\lor (r \lor \neg q)$$

Now use:

**DeMorgan**

$\neg(P \land Q) \Leftrightarrow \neg P \lor \neg Q$

$\neg(P \lor Q) \Leftrightarrow \neg P \land \neg Q$

Applied to what you got:

$$\neg (\neg p \lor q)\lor (r \lor \neg q) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$(\neg \neg p \land \neg q)\lor (r \lor \neg q) $$

Can you take it from here?

HINT: Use Commutation, Association, and Absorption

Comment: Yes, but how do I do after I get (p AND ~q) OR(~q OR r)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe his clue about absorption is the key. Look at that equivalence:
p ˅ (p ˄ q) ⇔ p. You have two ¬q with one ˄ p and the other ˅ with that combo. That facilitates the absorption equivalence so just reorder what you have with commutative law which is allowed as long as you only reorganize the ors:

¬q ˅ (p ˄ ¬q) ˅ r

¬q ˅ r via applying absorption in that the ¬q acts as the p in the above sample version.

Then I believe you can also apply implication in reverse and end up with q → r.

Fingers crossed that it correct as I am trying to figure this out also!